# Is there a way in qgis 2.0 to prevent overlapping labels?

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-2

Is there a way in qgis 2.0 to prevent overlapping labels?

I have a layer with a large geographical extent, which means a hell of a lot of labels. Many of them collide and it looks really bad. Is there a way for me to get qgis to automatically place the labels on an alternative 'location'?

I know it is possible in MapInfo but I'd rather use qgis :)

Comment: The label engine does that by default.  What options are you using?

Comment: I am using the 'Layer to labeled layer' option. Well, the default seems to be that it dows not allow colliding labels, but instead of moving them to an alternative location, it just doesn't show the colliding labels.

Comment: Labels-->Placement-->Free this will fix the issue.

Answer (score 6):

In the Layer properties select the **Label** page. In the **Rendering** subpage on the right you can select various options in the **Features category**.

You can limit the amount of Labels to be printed or merge connected line labels (this of course depends on the type of Feature used).

The placement of labels can be customized under the **Placement** subpage.

Comment: Ahh ok. I just saw the checkbox called 'Discourage labels from covering features'.

After I unchecked that box, colliding labels were moved to alternate positions. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I had the same problem few days ago. Glad to help!

Comment: Well....the problem was only 50 % solved :) I am using the 'Layer to labeled layer' option and if my labels are to big, they will overlap even if I've unchecked the box.

Did unchecking the box solve your problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand the problem, but to me - please correct me if wrong - it seems you have all Features on a single layer? Maybe splitting them to several layers and using the Priority setting in the _Placement_ page might help.

Comment: You understood the problem fully :) All the features are in a single layer. Splitting them up and using the Priority setting would not solve the problem. If labels would overlap, the priority setting would make only the higher priority label visible, thus leaving me exactly where I started.

In MapInfo, there is a button that says 'try alternative location for overlapping labels'. I just hoped that Qgis had a similar option but I guess that was to much to ask :)

Comment: It's kind of a catch-22. Well you have the option 'Discourage labels from covering features'. And the ability to limit the amount of displayed labels/features. I think more is not possible as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

Only practical if the number of labels are limited, but you can move the labels by using the "move labels and diagram" button

Comment: "Label Toolbar" sometimes is very useful as @user136727 said above.