# Colliding labels for point features in QGIS

Tags: labeling, point, qgis-2, point-of-interest

I have a layer (point features) containing various points of interest (POIs), some of them have the exact same location. I would like to map these POIs and add a label showing their names.
However, for those POIs that share the same location, QGIS just display the overlapping labels and it is not readable.

Is there a way in QGIS to automatically place labels for point features so that they never overlap, even though they belong to the same layer?

I found [this relevant thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74317/is-there-a-way-in-qgis-2-0-to-prevent-overlapping-labels), but no solution to the problem.

Comment: See this thread: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74317/is-there-a-way-in-qgis-2-0-to-prevent-overlapping-labels

Comment: Thanks, but I already saw it. I put this link in my question.

Comment: if you select "around point" on the labels placement tab QGIS tries to select the empty place around the point.

Comment: Labels-->Placement-->Free this will fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I feel your pain... However I was lucky enough to have only up to 10 labels on the same point feature.

By increasing the distance value (in my case 30.0000) under the placement tab in layer properties (around point = checked) i was able to see them aligned around some kind of circle; I suppose its radius is determined by the distance variable, see below. I also checked 'show all labels for this layer (including colliding labels)'.

[image]
[image]